# Numeros primos con bucles anidados

Tags: javascript, bucles, números-primos

Pueden ayudarme con este código, sé que realiza pero no entiendo del todo como lo hace. ¿Cómo funcionan en conjunto los bucles? Especialmente el bucle anidado.

```
let n = 15;
proximoPrimo: for(let i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
    
    for(let d = 2; d < i; d++) {
        if(i % d == 0) continue proximoPrimo; 
    }

    console.log(i);
}
```

Comment: Hola Adrian, bienvenido a StackOverflow. Te invito a hacer el [tour] para aprender sobre el funcionamiento del sitio y la comunidad y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. Un saludo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El `continue proximoPrimo` hace que no se ejecute nada de lo que viene abajo de esa instrucción, saltando directamente a la línea `proximoPrimo: for(let i = 2; i <= n; i++)`

Básicamente dice: He encontrado un número divisible, entonces no es primo!! así no me interesa seguir iterando, por lo que paso al siguiente número. Es la técnica que se usa para usar continue/brake de ciclos anidados. Es muy parecido a lo que en otros lenguajes se conoce como `GOTO` el cual en lenguajes de alto nivel está muy desaconsejado.

**¿Como sería el código sin usar ese `continue proximoPrimo`?**

```js
let n = 15;
for(let i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
    let esPrimo = true;
    for(let d = 2; d < i; d++) {
        if(i % d == 0){
          esPrimo=false;
          break;
        }
    }
    if(esPrimo){
       console.log(i);
    }
   
}
```

Como puedes ver necesitas crear una variable booleana que te indique si la segunda iteración ha encontrado un número divisible, esto con el fin de imprimir el `console.log(i)` si no fuese el caso.

Con el uso del `continue proximoPrimo` te ahorras todo eso. Porque toda la lógica del problema recae en que se ejecute o no la línea: `console.log(i)`.

Luego, colocar `continue` o `brake` (según como formules el código) es solo para hacerlo más eficiente.

Yo recomendaría usar una función aparte, ya que con el `return` podrás obtener el mismo efecto.

```js
let n = 15;

for(let i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
  if(esPrimo(i)) console.log(i);    
}

function esPrimo(i){
  for(let d = 2; d < i; d++) {
      if(i % d == 0) return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Por último, una mejora es iterar hasta la raíz cuadrada, así en el caso que sea  un primo muy grande no es necesario iterar hasta el final

```js
let n = 15;

for(let i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
  if(esPrimo(i)) console.log(i);    
}

function esPrimo(i){
  for(let d = 2; d <= Math.sqrt(i); d++) {
      if(i % d == 0) return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```